# Theorem 2.34 Baby Rudin (Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed): How is his proof general enough?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

> **2.34 Theorem** Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.
>
> Proof.
>
> Let $K$ be a compact subset of metric space $X$. Let $p\in K^c$, $q\in K$. Let $V_q, W_q$ be neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$ with radius less than $\frac{1}{2}d(p,q)$.
>
> Since $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $q_1,...,q_n\in K$ such that $K\subset W_{q_1}\cup \cdots\cup W_{q_n}=W$.
>
> If $V=V_{q_1}\cap \cdots \cap V_{q_n}$, then $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ which does not intersect $W$. Hence $V\subset K^c$ so that $p$ is an interior point of $K^c$.

The way I understand it, he has just shown that it is possible to construct a finite open cover of $K$ such that $p$ is in interior point in $K^c$, but it does not show that all finite open covers of $K$ have this property.

Is this proof actually complete?

Answer (score 3):

To prove $K^c$ is open, it suffices to show every point of $K^c$ is an interior point of $K^c$.  This is what the proof has done: it started with an arbitrary point $p\in K^c$, and proved it is an interior point.  So, the proof is complete.  It is totally irrelevant whether something holds for "all finitie open covers of $K$" (and in any case I am not sure what it is you wish to hold) since that is not what is being proved.

The proof is a bit unclear about this setup, particularly in the line

> Let $p\in K^c$, $q\in K$.

I would rephrase that instead as:

> Let $p\in K^c$.  Then for each $q\in K$, ...

This makes it clear that $p$ is fixed at the start and so the argument really does show an arbitrary $p\in K^c$ is an interior point.

Comment: Eric.Nice. Rudin's $q \in K, $ I would read as : and let q be in K.(Nitpicking:)) Greetings.

Comment: The issue that I have is that I cannot see how this proof shows that if $p\in K^c$ then $p$ is an internal point. I could have equally constructed an open cover of $K$, say, $\{X\}$, so that $W=X$, and then in this case, $V$ does intersect $W$, so we cannot conclude that $V\subset K^c$. Why is it that by finding a set of $W$ that works, we can say that this $p$ is an interior point of $K_c$?

Comment: @paul: By definition, $p$ is an interior point of $K^c$ if there _exists_ a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $V\subseteq K^c$.  We don't need it to be true for _every_ neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’ve been thinking about it overnight, and perhaps my question can be answered if I phrased it this way. Let’s assume that $K$ is a set that is not compact. Then, I cannot guarantee that every of $K$ contains a finite subcover of $K$. Am I not able to go through each line of reasoning, and still conclude that I can find a neighbourhood of $p$ that is interior to the complement of $K$?

Comment: No, the step "there are finitely many points..." may fail if $K$ is not compact.