# Baby Rudin 2.34 proof style and logical leaps

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

There are already maybe a dozen questions about this proof on this site. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118105/theorem-2-34-baby-rudin-compact-subsets-of-metric-spaces-are-closed-how-is-hi) contains the problem statement; I'm interested in the conclusion that there are finitely many points $q_i$ in $K$ which form a finite cover of $K$.

Here's my quibble: Denote a point in $K$ by $q_\alpha$. Rudin assumes that the union of open balls around every point $q_\alpha \in K$, all relative to the same arbitrary point in $p\in K^c$, such that the radius is $r < \frac{1}{2}d(q_\alpha,p)$, form an open cover of $K$ when $K$ is compact. Can we assume this without justification? It's equivalent to the statement:

> Given any point $q$ in a subset $E$ of metric space $X$, and a point $p$ in $E^c$, $d(p,q) > 0$.

The proof is simple of course: by definition of $d(p,q)$, $d(p,q)=0$ iff $p=q$, and if $p=q$ then $p\in E$; but $p \in E^c$, a contradiction which proves the theorem.

It's not a terrible assumption to make, this is basically just applying the definition of the distance function, but in the proof Rudin not only passes over the fact that such a cover exists, he goes straight to the fact that given any point $p$, there is a finite open cover of open balls about points $q_i$ in $K$ whose radii are less than half the distance from $q_i$ to $p$. Is this criticism just too pedantic? Would the proof be improved by noting why the cover exists, or is it considered better for brevity to leave the reasoning to the reader? Maybe it's a question in proof style, to what extent should we expect the reader to conclude things for themselves when previous statements are sufficient, and when should we call things out.

Comment: the fact that $K$ is compact is not used until a later step. You can cover any set by the (say, unit radius) balls at every point of the set. And yes I think this is an instance of " brevity to leave the reasoning to the reader"

Comment: How many details should be given is a matter of opinion. Obviously we can't explain every single statement in a proof, that would be way too much noise. On the other hand the "it is obvious" approach is sometimes too frivolous as well. Good balancing is a key, but there is no rule here, and I don't think anyone can answer such question.

Comment: I will add that Sam is doing the right thing here, slowly stepping through the reasoning and checking it. You should fill in the gaps in the reasoning until YOU are convinced.

Comment: @311411 the issue I have isnt that you can make a cover with open balls of fixed radius, but that you can make one when the radius is dependent on the distance to another point outside the set. Of course it does, but it's not absolutely straightforward, and I thought it mightve required a note.

Comment: @311411 Also thanks for the comments, still helpful!

Comment: When in doubt I prefer to give more detail and definitely preferred that my students do so, but in this case I do think that your concern is excessive. If $p\in E$ and $q\in X\setminus E$ it is utterly trivial that $p\ne q$ and hence that $d(p,q)>0$; I would not penalize a student who spelled this out in a proof of this theorem, but I would definitely point out that this is excessive detail even at an elementary level. I also consider it completely obvious that if for each $p\in E$ we have a set $A_p$ containing $p$, then $\bigcup_{p\in E}A_p\supseteq E$, though I do think that it would be ...

Comment: ... a bit better in that case to mention explicitly that $\{A_p:p\in E}$ covers $E$.